# Reduce varchar column size in a production database

Tags: mysql-8.0, alter-table, isolation-level, aws-aurora, varchar

We have a database running on AWS Aurora Mysql with version 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.04.1 as a regional database.

There is a table in it with a column with varchar size 200. We want to reduce it to varchar(85) without hampering the prod traffic. There is no way to stop incoming insert queries on this database.

Issuing a alter directly would lock the table in shared mode for ~40 mins which is not acceptable as insert queries would start timing out. The insert queries are ran with `SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED`. All tables have `Engine=InnoDB`

Options tried:

1. With binary logging turned on to with Row format, created a blue green replication. Performed the alter on the green(staging) cluster. Alter succeed but it failed to caught up to the master as it was not able to save the rows from the binary logs as they were of different(greater) size.

   Error:  cannot be converted from type 'varchar(600(bytes))' to type 'varchar(255(bytes) utf8)'
2. Binary logging turned on to with Statement format, gives the error: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since `BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT` and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is `READ COMMITTED` or `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Any options?

Edit:
Created a replicated cluster for testing purposes.
Tried out the alter when writer instance is `db.r5.xlarge` and when it's `db.r5.12xlarge`. Both the times the time required for the alter was the same (~40 mins). How? It seemed obvious that increasing the writer size would bring down the time.

Comment: stop all connections to the server, after a backup, change the database. maintenance is sometimes necessary even on 24/7 Servers , so discuss it with the manager, when is the best time to shut it down. And this is usually during the holidays.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this is not an option as I mentioned as in the question.

Comment: @TanmaySule from [Online DDL Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html) `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CHANGE COLUMN c1 c1 VARCHAR(255), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;` . It talks about increasing the varchar column, but I guess would be the same for decreasing . I have never tried before so I do not know if it will help you

Comment: For a reducing size, you need first check if there any rows that have more characters, even before you think about  changing anything. also backups backups backups in your case Replication replication replication and read the article tha @ErgestBasha posted very carefully about altering varchar

Comment: @ErgestBasha `Decreasing VARCHAR size using in-place ALTER TABLE is not supported. Decreasing VARCHAR size requires a table copy (ALGORITHM=COPY). `

Comment: Reducing the column size by even 1 is not support by `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`. 

So even `alter table ats_sync_activity modify column sync_type varchar(199) default null, algorithm=inplace, lock=none;` will give error.

For increasing, anything between varchar `0-255` and `255>` ranges will be supported by inplace algo [Extending VARCHAR column size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#:~:text=ALGORITHM%3DCOPY.-,Extending%20VARCHAR%20column%20size,-ALTER%20TABLE%20tbl_name). 

The table format here is `utf8mb3` to 1 char it atmost 3 bytes

Comment: @nbk
What do you mean by replication. Can you. explain in a little more detail?
As mentioned in the question, I have already tried binlog replication which was not helpful in this case.

Comment: You make  a backup, but a replication produces an exact copy of the data, so that even when the first server is down, you can switch even automatically to the second server, if the sql server is so heavily used, that you can't shut it down for 40 seconds, you need a copy of the production server and make there the wanted change then switch both servers and add the sql commands that were made between backup and switching, so you need a tome where not much happens. That said you must always have a functioning backup for emergencies and replication is needed so that the show can go on, if it fail

Comment: As mentioned, I have already tried `ROW` and `STATEMENT` replication (I believe `MIXED` will give the same error as `ROW`).
Which replication are you suggesting here?